# Replace Pythons builtin type with custom one

Tags: python, object, types, built-in

Is it possible to replace some built-in python types with custom ones?

I want to create something like:

```
class MyInt(object):
   ...
__builtin__.int = MyInt
x = 5
```

Comment: It *almost* sounds like there's a real problem behind this one that you need solved...

Comment: No, there is no problem. I programm in python for several years and now I want to use it as a front end for some specialistic low-level language. It is only a test and I want to see how it could be solved :)

Comment: So then your question is "how do I implement a DSL in Python?" and that *does* have a good answer. That the DSL has the same syntax as Python is irrelevant.

Comment: Not exactly - I want to simply trace what user has used. For example: if user writes a=5; b=6; x=a+b; I want to get graph representing sum of two ints (in Python).

Comment: Well you can't. So you use a DSL instead.

Comment: Did anyone find a workaround for this? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be asking if it's possible to override the type that is created when you enter *literals*.  The answer is no.  You cannot make it so that `x = 5` uses a type other than the built-in `int` type.

You can override `__builtin__.int`, but that will only affect explicit use of the name `int`, e.g., when you do `int("5")`.  There's little point to doing this; it's better to just use your regular class and do `MyInt("5")`.

More importantly, you *can* provide operator overloading on your classes so that, for instance, `MyInt(5) + 5` works and returns another MyInt.  You'd do this by writing an  `__add__` method for your MyInt class (along with `__sub__` for subtraction, etc.).

Comment: Is it possible to override these types with Python C extension or something like that?

Comment: I don't know enough about the C interface to know if you can override them with a C extension.  You could certainly override them by making custom modifications to the interpreter source and compiling your own interpreter.  That's a lot of work just to avoid typing half a dozen characters though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about *replacing* the built-ins, but you can certainly create an object that inherits from them, and/or behaves like them. Look up something like `inherit from immutable` and you should find answers that show overriding of `__new__`, or for the latter option see '[Emulating Numeric Types](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__iadd__#emulating-numeric-types)'

Comment: Thank you, I know I can inherit from immutables but I wanted to replace some of them :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to write a Pythonesque DSL, you have two options:

1. Compile the code to an AST and walk the AST replacing nodes as appropriate.
2. Build your own AST by hand.

Once you have the AST you can go ahead and execute it directly. In either case, look at [Python's Language Services](http://docs.python.org/library/language.html) for generation and manipulation of the AST.