# Subclassing int class in Python

Tags: python-3.x, built-in, subclassing

I want to do something every time I add two integers in my `TestClass`.

```
import builtins

class myInt(int):
    def __add__(self, other):
        print("Do something")

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        builtins.int = myInt

    def testMethod(self):
        a = 1
        b = 2
        c = a + b
```

When I call my `testMethod` nothing happens, however if I define it like this I get the desired effect:

```
    def testMethod(self):
        a = int(1)
        b = 2
        c = a + b
```

Is it possible to make this work for all int literals without having to typecast them before the operations?

Comment: Short answer: Nope.

Comment: Lots of discussion on this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/11787922/9742036

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, it's not possible without building your own custom interpreter. Literal objects aren't constructed by calling the constructor in `__builtins__`, they are constructed using opcodes that directly call the builtin types.

Also immutable literals are constructed when the code is compiled, so you were too late anyway. If you disassemble `testMethod` you'll see it simply uses the constants that were compiled, it doesn't attempt to construct them:

```
>>> dis.dis(TestClass.testMethod)
  5           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 STORE_FAST               1 (a)

  6           4 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              6 STORE_FAST               2 (b)

  7           8 LOAD_FAST                1 (a)
             10 LOAD_FAST                2 (b)
             12 BINARY_ADD
             14 STORE_FAST               3 (c)
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

Mutable literals are constructed at runtime but they use opcodes to construct the appropriate value rather than calling the type:

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: {'a': 1, 'b': 2})
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              4 LOAD_CONST               3 (('a', 'b'))
              6 BUILD_CONST_KEY_MAP      2
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

You *could* do something along the lines of what you want by parsing the source code (use builtin `compile()` with `ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST` flag) then walking the parse tree and replacing `int` literals with a call to your own type (use `ast.NodeTransformer`). Then all you have to do is finish the compilation (use `compile()` again). You could even do that with an import hook so it happens automatically when your module is imported, but it will be messy.